# how to get correct path for file stored in My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData folder under installer class

Tags: vb.net, deployment, .net-4.0

I have a windows forms application which stores data in

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData + "\a.xml"
```

When I run and test this path, it shows path as:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\<Manufacture name>\<Product Name>\1.0.0.0\a.xml
```

I want to delete above file at the time of uninstall.

So I have created custom action using installer class (please note that I have created installer class in main project, not in setup project as setup project does not show option to add installer class). In installer class, I have override uninstall method and using same above code

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData + "\a.xml"
```

I have tried to delete file. Obviously I have pointed it to uninstall folder in setup project which should delete above file, but I can see that in setup project above is taking different path. It is taking path as

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft Corporation\Windows Installer - Unicode\5.0.7600.16385\a.xml
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013. Please suggest how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest workaround I found for this issue is to change the version number so no need to delete any file as it is creating different directory for different version number.